# .htaccess Messy Rewrite Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I could do with some assistance trying to clean up an .htaccess file that has been running on one of our servers at work.

It is currently set up so that if someone types `example.com` it will redirect to `www.example.com`. The problem is that we want to utilise subdomains but when we try to add a subdomain, like `beta.example.com` it will redirect to `www.beta.example.com`

Here is the `.htaccess` file

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have tried multiple variations from questions here on SO and via Google and htaccess generators and none of them seem to help as they usually put the site in a redirect loop.

Any help on getting the configuration correct would be appreciated.

-- Chris

Comment: specify a document root tree along with index.php and htaccess

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you have code examples?

Comment: It's not clear where the index.php and htaccess lays relative to site document root

Comment: `.htaccess` is in the same folder as the `index.php` file

Comment: whether this folder is a document root? Note, the `$1` is a request_uri with discarded prefix from root upto the current folder. Use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead, without a front slash.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically add a www to your domain name when there isn't a subdomain, add this to the htaccess file in your document root::`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: This kind of works. Except, the site has a portal `www.example.com/dashboard/portal` and when you go to that after changing the `.htaccess` the portal shows a 404 not found.